# Как в aiogram считать данные пользователя из его сообщения?

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Всем доброго времени суток!
Недавно решил попробовать написать своего первого Tg-бота на aiogram, но столкнулся с проблемой со считыванием данных из сообщения пользователя.

По задумке пользователь через запятую (без пробелов) перечисляет несколько параметров, функция считывает их из сообщения и заносит в список с помощью метода split(). Далее при помощи индексов в функцию обработки передаются получившиеся элементы этого списка и еще 5 из другого (до этого момента все идет нормально). После этого программа с помощью reply-кнопок спрашивает пользователя, стоит ли сохранить данные в базе, и при нажатии на любую из кнопок почему-то выдает ошибку IndexError: list index out of range.

[image: IndexError: list index out of range]
Других операций со списком student_data не было.

'''
await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id,
text='Введи через запятую (без пробелов) 6 параметров')

```
                    @dp.message_handler(content_types='text')
                    async def full_name(msg: types.Message):
                        data = msg.text
                        student_data = data.split(",")
                        cd.create_title(param0=title_data[0], param1=title_data[1], param2=title_data[4],
                                        department=student_data[2], param4=student_data[4],
                                        param5=student_data[3], param6=student_data[1], param7=title_data[2],
                                        param8=title_data[3], param9=student_data[0])

                        async def save_title_data():
                            await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id, text='Сохранить введенные данные на будущее?',
                                               reply_markup=kb.save_title_data)

                            @dp.message_handler(text='Да')
                            async def save_title(callback_query):
                                await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id,
                                               text='Принято. Твои данные сохранены в базе.',
                                               reply_markup=kb.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
                                # Сохраняем данные пользователя в перманентную БД

                            @dp.message_handler(text='Нет')
                            async def save_title(callback_query):
                                await bot.send_message(callback_query.from_user.id,
                                               text='Принято. Твои данные не сохранены в базе.',
                                               reply_markup=kb.ReplyKeyboardRemove())
                                # Сохраняем данные пользователя в оперативную БД, которая очищается после окончания сеанса
                        await save_title_data()'''
```

Скажите, пожалуйста, как можно исправить эту ошибку?

P.S. Разумная критика логики построения функции тоже приветствуется

Comment: Нужно использовать машину состояний, прочитай про это. Ну и чтобы понять в чём ошибка выведи то, что у тебя в data

Comment: Спасибо, обязательно изучу эту тему. Я перепроверил: в data без проблем попадает текст, который ввел пользователь. То же и со списком student_data: элементы в него добавляются (во всяком случае, print(student_data) выдает список ответов, как и должно быть), но почему-то ошибка с индексами сохраняется. Что характерно, она выпадает не сразу, а как только пользователь перейдет к следующей функции (сохранение данных), и функция cd.create_title() свою работу выполняет (она должна вставлять введенные параметры в файл и сохранять его).